# Encapsulating a private constant

Tags: c#, oop

I am just wondering if I have a constant attribute, can I set a public property to encapsulate it?

e.g.

```
private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200;
public int default_charge
{
     get { return DEFAULT_CHARGE; }
}
```

I don't get any errors but if something is constant I don't really understand the logic of why we encapsulate it. I really want to understand why this is:

1. right/wrong
2. why do it?
3. benefits?

Comment: One very important reason: the compiler can (and will) expand constants at the place where they're compiled. In other words, changing the value and distributing a new assembly will not cause clients to actually use a new value until they are recompiled. Sometimes this is what you want, often it's not (and other times it doesn't matter since you won't be replacing individual assemblies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to know that constants are *inlined* by the compiler. It means that these two examples result in the same program:

```
private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200;
public int default_charge
{
     get { return DEFAULT_CHARGE; }
}
```

Is the same as this, after compiling:

```
public int default_charge
{
     get { return 200; }
}
```

As you can see, the reference to `DEFAULT_CHARGE` is lost after compiling. That is important to remember for solutions where you reuse the same constants in multiple projects.

Let's say you use `DEFAULT_CHARGE` as a `public const` in LibA and LibB. Your project manager tells you to change the value from 200 to 300. Instinctively, you go to LibA where `DEFAULT_CHARGE` is defined, you change it to 300 and then you re-compile and deploy only LibA.

The result is that LibA now uses the new value of 300 but LibB keeps using the old value of 200, because the constant was baked into the DLL at compile-time.

The reason why you might encapsulate the constant is so that you can more easily change the value. Requirements tend to change over time. A `DEFAULT_CHARGE` value that is constant today might have to be replaced by a configuration value in the future.

By encapsulating the constant, you also prevent the problem that I just explained. If both LibA and LibB (and LibX, LibY,LibZ,...) depend on the encapsulation, you only need to recompile and deploy LibA to set the default charge in all dependent programs.

Comment: That is such a clear explanation, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Even if something is constant you could still want control over how it is returned to the caller. If you have a have a Double variable  that is store to 5 decimal places you could  want to return the value to the caller in 2 decimal places. Encapsulation helps you get this control over your fields.

So you might need to encapsulate a constant field like this

```
private const double DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200.12345;
   public int default_charge
 {
 get { return Math.round(DEFAULT_CHARGE,2); }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to implement `interface`, `abstract class` etc.:

```
   public interface IChargable {
     int default_charge {get;}
   }

   public class MySimpleChargable: IChargable {
     private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200;

     public int default_charge {get { return DEFAULT_CHARGE; }} 
   }
```

You may implement such a construction as a *stub*:

Initial:

```
   // Version 1.0
   public class MyChargable {
     private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200;

     //TODO: implement (rare) "some condition" case
     public int default_charge {get { return DEFAULT_CHARGE; }} 
   }
```

Later:

```
   // Version 1.1
   public class MyChargable {
     private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200;

     public int default_charge {
       get { 
         if (some condition)
           return SomeComputation();

         return DEFAULT_CHARGE; 
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helped

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements.
In general, properties are designed to encapsulate any getting / setting logic you want, even calculable values or constants.
In my opinion, public property returning a value of a private constant is good in terms of architecture, in this case someone who uses your code doesn't know that he works with constant at all, i.e. he is abstracted from your implementation, and that's good. If you decide to make it not a constant, but configurable value, then you wouldn't expose it to your library consumer, you just make it like:

```
// private const int DEFAULT_CHARGE = 200; <-- is not used anymore

public int DefaultCharge
{
    get { return SomeSortOfFileOrDatabaseConfiguration.DefaultCharge; }
}
```

or even

```
public int DefaultCharge
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentUser.PersonalSettings.DefaultCharge; 
    }
}
```

which makes this code rely on users' personal settings without telling anything to your clients.

That's the main benefit. It is all about encapsulation and abstraction.

But please use proper naming for properties - it should be `public int DefaultCharge`, and pay attention to Jeroen Mostert's comment about constant inlining.

Comment: You guys are the best, thanks so much! I think I get the theory and rationale behind it now! Really hope one day I'm on your level! :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can create an public accessor to a private constant no problems.

You should create an accessor to a constant when:

1. You need to add extra logic to a getter like return it formated in some way or other value if a condition applies.
2. Your constant is part of a namespace that is used as library for other namespace, since if you compile the namespace on which the constant exists, the dependant namespace will only remember the old value of the constant, as it was defined on compilation.